# glb/gltf Model not loading on Netlify, but loads locally

Tags: three.js, xmlhttprequest, netlify, gltf

I am using Three.js with the gltf loader to load a single .glb resource onto a page. It works locally, though then I upload to Netlify the model does not load and the xhr progressEvent's total is 0. I checked that the model is still being loaded in the network tab, but yet it still does not show in the page.

It seems this problem has occurred before, but not sure how to resolve it when using Netlify if there are any environment variables I need to change.
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/15584

HTML

```
    <div class="model-wrapper">
      <div id="model_target" class="loading"> 
        <div class="myimage fade" id="placeholder">
           <img src="images/placeholder.png" height="328px"/></div>
            </div>
       </div>

    <!-- THREE.js -->
    <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>

    <!-- GLTFLoader.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/r92/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
```

````
JS
```


   let camera, scene, renderer;
                    const mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
                    const look = new THREE.Vector2();
                    const windowHalf = new THREE.Vector2( window.innerWidth / 
     2, window.innerHeight / 2 );
                    var plane = new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0.4), 
     -9);
                    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
                    var pointOfIntersection = new THREE.Vector3();
                    let modelLoaded = false;

                    let placement = document.getElementById("model_target")



                    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);


                    function init() {

                        scene = new THREE.Scene();

                        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, 1, 1, 1000);
                        camera.position.set(5, 3, 28)
                        //camera.position.y = 13;


                        var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight("#fff", 1.5); 
                        var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight("#FFF");
                        light.position.set( 0, -70, 100 ).normalize();
                        scene.add(light);
                       // scene.add(ambient);

                        var texture = new THREE.Texture();

                        var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

                        THREE.Cache.enabled = true;

                        // Load a glTF resource
                        loader.load(
                            // 3d model resource 
                            './assets/models/mrktechy3.glb',
                            // called when the resource is loaded
                            function ( gltf ) {

                                    mesh = gltf.scene;
                                    mesh.scale.set( 5, 5, 5 );
                                    scene.add( mesh );

                            },
                            // called when loading is in progress
                            function ( xhr ) {

                                    // Loading progress of model
                                    console.log(xhr);
                                    console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );
                                    if((xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) == 100){
                                        modelLoaded = true;

                                        //Loading overlay
                                        var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder");
                                        placeholder.classList.add("faded");
                                        placement.classList.remove("loading");
                                    }

                            },
                            // called when loading has errors
                            function ( error ) {

                                    console.log( 'An error happened' );

                            }
                        );


                        //scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xfff); //Set background color 


                        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true, antialias: true  } );
                        renderer.setSize( 800, 500 );

                        placement.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                        renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0); 
                        renderer.gammaOutput = true;

                        document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );

                        window.addEventListener( 'resize', onResize, false );

                        render()

                    } 

                    function onMouseMove( event ) {

                        if (modelLoaded){
                            mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 0;
                        mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 0;

                        raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
                        raycaster.ray.intersectPlane(plane, pointOfIntersection);
                        mesh.lookAt(pointOfIntersection);
                        }

                    }



                    function onResize( event ) {

                        const width = 800 ;
                        const height = 500;

                        windowHalf.set( width / 2, height / 2 );

                        camera.aspect = width / height;
                        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
                        renderer.setSize( width, height );     
                    }

                    var easeAmount = 8;

                    function update(){
                        look.x += (mouse.x-look.x)/easeAmount;
                        look.y += (mouse.y-look.y)/easeAmount;
                        raycaster.setFromCamera(look, camera);
                        raycaster.ray.intersectPlane(plane, pointOfIntersection);
                        mesh.lookAt(pointOfIntersection);
                    }



                    function render() {

                        camera.aspect = renderer.domElement.clientWidth / renderer.domElement.clientHeight;
                        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                        requestAnimationFrame( render );

                        if (modelLoaded){
                            update();
                        }

                        renderer.render( scene, camera );

                    }                 
  ```
````

Any glb resource can be replaced in the code and it works locally but not when hosted.

Comment: Have you tried updating to the latest version of GLTFLoader? You're using r92, but I think they're on r108 by now.

Comment: @Marquizzo Just updated to the latest version and same problem still occurs :/

Comment: Have you tried logging the actual error, rather than "An error happened", and checking the JS console for other errors?

Comment: @DonMcCurdy my bad, just changed it to output the error. Though, the error is never even thrown on the xhr object because it shows it still loads. I think it might have to do with netlify, instead of three.js? I'm posting pictures below for more detail

Comment: i have the same issue currently

Answer (score 0):

In the IIS settings, try to add mime type for gltf. Something like this:

`application/gltf-buffer .gltf`

This solved my problem.